# In metpy i would like to create skew-t plot animations does anyone know how to do that?

Tags: python, matplotlib, weather

So in metpy i want to create a basic skew t plot that has animations with near real time data
but i don't know what function to use and i already looked up some skew-t plot animations but couldn't find any any suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was save each frame of the skewT plot as a png image then used imageio to put the images into a gif.

First, imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import pandas as pd
import metpy as mp
import numpy as np
import metpy.plots as plots
from metpy.units import units
import glob
import imageio
```

I had every CSV (containing the skewT data) in the same directory, and I used glob to glob the filenames together:

```
df = []
titleNames = []

files = glob.glob("*.csv")
for a in files:
    df.append(pd.read_csv(a))
    titleNames.append(a[0:10])
    
#print(titleNames)
```

titleNames is an list of the file names without the ".csv", so I can name each skewT image corresponding to their filename. Next, I defined a skewT plotting function and saved each of those images into the current directory with the for loop at the bottom.

```
def skewT(dataframe, i):
    
    titleName = titleNames[i][0:4] + "Dec_" + titleNames[i][4:10]
    
    temp = np.array(dataframe.temp)*units.degC
    dew = np.array(dataframe.dew)*units.degC
    p = np.array(dataframe.press)*units.hPa
    wspd = np.array(dataframe.wspd)*units.knots
    wdir = np.array(dataframe.wdir)*units.degrees
    u, v = mp.calc.wind_components(wspd, wdir)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    skew = plots.SkewT(fig, rotation=45)
    skew.ax.set_ylim(1000, 10)
    skew.plot_dry_adiabats()
    skew.plot_moist_adiabats()
    skew.plot_mixing_lines()
    skew.ax.set_ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')
    skew.ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (℃)')

    
    skew.plot(p, temp, 'r')
    skew.plot(p, dew, 'g')
    skew.plot_barbs(p, u, v)
    
    title = plt.title(u"{}".format(titleName))

for i in range(len(titleNames)):
    skewT(df[i], i)
    plt.savefig('test_{}.png'.format(titleNames[i]))
```

After each image was saved into the directory, I used glob to glob them together and used imageio to produce a gif:

```
images = []
filenames = glob.glob("*.png")

for filename in filenames:
    images.append(imageio.imread(filename))
imageio.mimsave('BNA_SkewT.gif', images, duration = 0.5)
```

[Produces a GIF like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7d1d.gif)